# how to set the radio button when you want to display it on the data update page

Tags: php, html

how can I choose the value of the radio button according to what is in the database?

my code :

```html
    <tr>
        <td>Jenis Kelamin</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="M">M
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="F">L</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. Have you tried to use the attribute ```checked```? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to catch data from database, you only have to check which gender you got from the database.

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="F" <?php if ($type == 'F') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>" />Female<br />
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="M" <?php if ($type == 'M') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>" />Male<br />
```